# write where condition for joined table

Tags: java, spring, jpa, predicate, hibernate-criteria

I have 2 tables
table `user` have these fields
`userId`
`email`
`Phone`
`activeFlag`

Table `Comments` have these fields
`userId`
`Comments`
`Flag`

I want to create end query like this

`Select * from users a left join Comments b on a.user_id and b.user_id where a.activeFlag='Y' and b.Flag='Y' and a.userId='myuser'`

I have created mapping for both the tables where both the table are mapping with OneToOne mapping

I have written below predicates for it

```
public static Specification<User> findUser(String username){
        return ((root,criteriaQuery,cb) ->{
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
            
            
            Root<Comments> rootComment = criteriaQuery.from(Comments.class);
            predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("userId"),username));
            predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("activeFlag"),"N"));
            
            
            criteriaQuery.where(
                    cb.equal(rootComment.get("Flag"),"N")
                    );
            
            return  cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
            
    }
```

But it is not working as expected.
it is generating below query and its not including where clause for Flag

`select comment0_.user_id as user_id1_2_0_, comment0_.active_flag as active_f2_2_0_, comment0_.comments as comments3_2_0_, comment0_.create_date as create_d4_2_0_, comment0_.create_user_id as create_u5_2_0_ from comment comment0_ where comment0_.user_id=?`

Comment: Is a JPA Query an option for you or must it be Criteria Query?

Comment: yes we can use jpa too

Comment: I'm still not sure what should be the result of the query: A list of comments? A list of users? Mixture of both (which can't be converted to a java object directly)?

Comment: one user will have one comment.
but since I have onetoOne mapping with `comments` table that is also getting executed
so end result will be user data with his comment data

Comment: You know about Springs `JPARepository`? This would be lot easier for simple query like that than use jpql queries or cirteria queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using Springs `JPARepository` since its lot easier than using jpql/criteria queries for what you described.

I assume following model from your description:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private String userId;

    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private boolean activeFlag;

    @OneToOne
    private Comment comment;

    // Getters + Settes
}

@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id
    private String userId;

    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private boolean activeFlag;

    @OneToOne
    private User user;

}
```

Than you could use following repository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {
    User findByUserIdAndActiveFlagTrue(String userId);
}
```

And use it somewhere like that:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SomeClass(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public User findUser(String userName) { // Should be userId, but I match your example
        var user = userRepository.findByUserIdAndActiveFlagTrue(userName);
        return user;
    }

    public void useIt(){
        var myuser = findUser("myuser");

        //access user data
        myuser.getEmail();

        //access comment
        var comment = myuser.getComment();
        comment.getComments(); //comments field from your description
    }
}
```

I would suggest reading this baeldung tutorial for better understanding: https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

Generally: for me it seems you should rethink your model design because:

- A oneToOne relationship between User and Comment seems weird. Does a use can only have one comment at all time? I think you try avoid using manyToMany since Comments have a field `comments` (plural) where you probably store more than one comment.
- User and Comment have the same named Id column `userId`. Just name it `id` an it should be unique and not shared between user and the comment the user owns
- userId is String: It's not generally wrong but it cant be autoincremented or auto generated for example. Furthermore you use the username as an id, which you should avoid. Search for "natural key vs surrogate key" on the internet. I would recommend using a `Long` as id or even better an UUID (both surrogate key)